# How do I specify the color of an ellipsoid in a CZML document?

Tags: javascript, json, types, cesiumjs, czml

How do I specify the color of an ellipsoid in CZML? This snippet works when I add an entity to the viewer from within the JavaScript:

```
let redEllipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
  "name": "red ellipsoid",
  "position": Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-114.0, 40.0, 300000.0),
  "ellipsoid": {
    "radii": new Cesium.Cartesian3(200000.0, 200000.0, 300000.0),
    "material": Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    "outline": true,
    "outlineColor": Cesium.Color.BLACK
  }
});
```

This other snippet also works:

```
let redEllipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
  "name": "red ellipsoid",
  "position": {
    x: -2083516.9683773473,
    y: -4679655.730028949,
    z: 4270821.855106338
  },
  "ellipsoid": {
    "radii": {
      x: 200000,
      y: 200000,
      z: 300000
    },
    "material": Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    "outline": true,
    "outlineColor": {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0,
      alpha: 1
    }
  }
});
```

But this snippet doesn't work (yields an ellipsoid with the default white):

```
let redEllipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
  "name": "red ellipsoid",
  "position": {
    x: -2083516.9683773473,
    y: -4679655.730028949,
    z: 4270821.855106338
  },
  "ellipsoid": {
    "radii": {
      x: 200000,
      y: 200000,
      z: 300000
    },
    "material": {
      "solidColor": {
        "color": {
          "rgba": [1, 0, 0, 0.5]
        }
      }
    },
    "outline": true,
    "outlineColor": {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0,
      alpha: 1
    }
  }
});
```

And neither does this one (also yields an ellipsoid with the default white):

```
let redEllipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
  "name": "red ellipsoid",
  "position": {
    x: -2083516.9683773473,
    y: -4679655.730028949,
    z: 4270821.855106338
  },
  "ellipsoid": {
    "radii": {
      x: 200000,
      y: 200000,
      z: 300000
    },
    "material": {
      "color": {
        red: 1,
        green: 0,
        blue: 0,
        alpha: 0.5
      }
    },
    "outline": true,
    "outlineColor": {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0,
      alpha: 1
    }
  }
});
```

And neither does this one (also yields an ellipsoid with the default white):

```
let redEllipsoid = viewer.entities.add({
  "name": "red ellipsoid",
  "position": {
    x: -2083516.9683773473,
    y: -4679655.730028949,
    z: 4270821.855106338
  },
  "ellipsoid": {
    "radii": {
      x: 200000,
      y: 200000,
      z: 300000
    },
    "material": {
      red: 1,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0,
      alpha: 0.5
    },
    "outline": true,
    "outlineColor": {
      red: 0,
      green: 0,
      blue: 0,
      alpha: 1
    }
  }
});
```

I am particularly confused, since feeding `Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5)` into the console after Cesium has loaded returns `ne {red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5}`. One would expect that giving the object specified by the static member would work...

Here is the [type of `"material"`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/MaterialProperty.html). Since it's an abstract class with no attributes, am I out of luck in specifying it via CZML? It would be a real drag if the only way to set the color of an ellipsoid required post-processing, since I want to be able to do the heavy lifting offline, and just load the CZML in the browser.

Edit: The CZML documentation is hard to find and navigate, but the direct answers are there:

See the [`Ellipsoid` page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Ellipsoid), [`Material` page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Material), [`SolidColorMaterial` page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/SolidColorMaterial), [`Color` page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/Color), and optionally the [`RgbaValue` page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/RgbaValue) of the [CZML documentation](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki). It's formatted as a GitHub wiki with a page per item, which unfortunately means that the vast majority of documentation items are hidden until you click `show 128 more pages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that [EntityCollection.add(...)](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/EntityCollection.html#add) takes [Entity.ConstructorOptions](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Entity.html#.ConstructorOptions) which are similar, but distinctly different in certain ways, from CZML.  Your first few working snippets in your question are using the ConstructorOptions correctly, and they do not handle colors or positions exactly as CZML does.

To convert your code to raw CZML, one would use `CzmlDataSource.load(...)` on the CZML content.  For example: [Sandcastle live demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=hVRdb5swFP0rFk+ZxMxXCCSl0aTscdImdepLyYODvdSasZFtUjUT/322gYQsqEMI4fPhe4yvqQRXGlTnmoFH8FJyAP7YBwAUb0DpYVG1NeG69PwePhGpqOCWi2A4wJ0/MZYexaVnBZJgQBijjRIW8keeo5p8rGiEotqUsaphWgtXSGqiKHL4y4gD8DkO8ySNVnC9ypMsS5ZZ4k/Y5Spbr9IUZkkYxvl6uZ6QyzgL8ziCeZpG4SpJ8pHa9y/dJdMk500oiTClN9hHUQGIQ3v5/4ESB12R/fja+dfSNdJEUsTuqivBKN4JJuQ/lIs2i7ulHA/I5Y3T1Aehu6M430913XXQzWUSrWaUu/3VsiX3zFws0wcbMP0AR0kIv4UOrCW3CGLNK9qA6BJj2DJXbmjL/UPJS165Lj9R8kak6XNO3sDO7E5bw2eHLcxXceOd4BqZkCbgp4fRh5FGT6KVFfkhRU0VMVMM9p05OF8vNGQC4YU9TNbcl4NXt4II48XdbBPtWYj6p5iXlNzzvULpd0a244q/0LoRUoNWsgWEgSZ1w0xPqODQVr+JhpVS1mqlRTC1FpiezBF/nFk3qBhSyjC/Wsae6Nls5bYIjP7OaldL+fG7+Scw9G5lr9H2Ww9CCIvADOedWgh2QHIyc6/4Cw)

```js
const czml = [
  {
    id: "document",
    version: "1.0",
  },
  {
    "id": "red ellipsoid",
    "name": "red ellipsoid",
    "position": {
      "cartesian": [
        -2083516.9683773473,
        -4679655.730028949,
        4270821.855106338
      ]
    },
    "ellipsoid": {
      "radii": {
        "cartesian": [
          200000,
          200000,
          300000
        ]
      },
      "material": {
        "solidColor": {
          "color": {
            "rgba": [255, 0, 0, 128]
          }
        }
      },
      "outline": true,
      "outlineColor": {
        red: 0,
        green: 0,
        blue: 0,
        alpha: 1
      }
    }    
  },
];

const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
const dataSourcePromise = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSourcePromise);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSourcePromise);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm curious: Is there a good reason for this inconsistency, or is it simply a consequence of CZML being mostly abandoned (there are multiple dead links in [the documentation](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/wiki/CZML-Guide), which is in some random repository that hasn't been touched since 2016).

Comment: This inconsistency is in some ways a legacy artifact. It would certainly make sense to me to have a way to initialize a single entity from a CZML snippet.  But the CZML parsing happens in CzmlDataSource instead of the entity itself, and it would be a large refactor to move it.  I'm surprised it hasn't been requested more in the past, but it seems unlikely to change much now.

Comment: The broken links should be fixed, of course.  Can you report the broken links here?  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/czml-writer/issues  Thanks!

Comment: Should I be using CesiumJS and/or CZML if I want my project to be maintainable 4 years down the road?

Comment: I believe it will be stable.  It's not under heavy development, but it's certainly not going to get deprecated or removed as far as I can tell.  It's been stable, if a bit stagnant, for many years and will most likely continue to be so.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll make sure to report broken links from now on. (I just didn't want to do so if CZML was going to become abandonware)